# Вывести список выбранных значений из select

Tags: javascript, html

Есть `<select>` на странице.

```
<div id="weeklyID" class=" multisel-container">
    <label class=" multisel-label" for="groupFormReportsInput">Назначьте
        показатели</label>
    <div class=" select-container">
        <select id="selectId" class="multisel selectpicker" multiple
            name="week_days">
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

он с функцией множественного выбора (`multisel selectpicker`)

рядом есть кнопочка

```
<input type="button" value=" >> " onclick="isUserId()">
```

при ее нажатии в соседнем `div`

```
<div id='resultId'></div>
```

должны выводиться выбранные option

написан вот такой простой js

```
function isUserId() {
    let id = document.getElementById('selectId');
    let selectShiftTypeId = id.value;
    document.getElementById('resultId').innerHTML = selectShiftTypeId;
}
```

В настоящий момент, при выбирании нескольких элементов в `<select>`, выводиться только один. А как переписать код, чтобы выводились все выбранные элементы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function isUserId() {
  document.getElementById('resultId').innerHTML = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#selectId option')).filter(option => option.selected).map(x => x.value).join();
}
```

```css
option {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="weeklyID" class=" multisel-container">
  <label class=" multisel-label" for="groupFormReportsInput">Назначьте
                        показатели</label>
  <div class=" select-container">
    <select id="selectId" class="multisel selectpicker" multiple name="week_days">
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="isUserId()">
<br>
<div id='resultId'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function isUserId() {
    let id = document.getElementById('selectId');
    let selectShiftTypeId='';
    for(var val of id.selectedOptions){
      selectShiftTypeId+=val.value;
    }
    document.getElementById('resultId').innerHTML = selectShiftTypeId;
}
```